# How to get thread status..in Multi threading

Tags: c#, multithreading

May be it sound dumb but if I want some computed value from other thread and other value from one more thread and this two value in my main thread how can I,if In case second thread completed before first one.it will create problem..so I just want is there any way that I can get the thread status means its still running or stop.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want to wait until both threads have finished. Simply call [Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/95hbf2ta.aspx) on each of them. After the calls have returned, you know that both threads have finished.

Answer (score 1):

`Thread` class have `ThreadState` property, but make sure you know about thread synchronization. Here are two articles:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dsw9f9ts%28VS.71%29.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188793.aspx

Answer (score 0):

`Thread.ThreadState` or `Thread.Join` if you want to wait for your threads. Or use `Semaphore`